# Angular JS routing between two pages at start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a situation where I want to either route a intranet user to the default start page (if they have used the app before or take them to the "how to use" / tutorial page if they have not used the app before.

The user identify is known and we have a flag held against user identities, so i can tell if a user has used the app before. When they follow the link from the tutorial. The controller on the tutorial sets and persists this flag via an ajax call.

What I basically want to be able to do is:

```
angular.module('uiApp', ['meModule'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'me', function($routeProvider, me)) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
         templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
         controller: 'homeCtrl',
         tab: 'home'
      }) 
      .when(' ... ', {
        ... other routes ...
      }) 
      .when('/tutorial', {
         templateUrl: '/views/tutorial.html',
         controller: 'tutorialCtrl'
      }) 
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: (me.isNew ? '/tutorial' : '/home')
      }); 
    }
  }])
  .run() {
    ..  the run code here
  }
```

So basically the idea being that a browser navigating to intranet.company.com/ with will always fall into otherwise and should for existing users take them to '/home' but for first timers will take them to '/tutorial'

The issue is that I can't seem to pass in the module that returns the user information and get a failed to instantiate module uiApp due to unknown provider: messages

and I'm uncertain how I would achieve this routing situation in the .run
section.

Can anyone turn me around and point me in the right direction?

Comment: I do something similar in one of my apps, however, it happens if a user tries to access a page that requires authentication. If they aren't authenticated, I route them to the login screen. On your /home controller, you could route them to /tutorial if they are new. Would that work?

Comment: Yes - it is something that I initially considered, adding the redirect into he controller code, but then I got to wondering was it possible to provide a way that kept all the routing logic together, making it clearer what was happening. That way others developers / support engineers could see it all at a glance and not have to go hunting  through the various  controllers to work out what was happening.

Comment: makes perfect sense. I would like to know this as well

Comment: You could use the $RouteChangeStart event if you want total control of where the user can and should go. In the run method can't you just use the location service to direct to the view you want?

Comment: yes it woul dbe possible -buit the 'gothca' is that you then have implicit understanding of the otherwise and you don't if the route being requested is going to be handled unless you right something like if  ! ( ( '/users' || '/home' || '/tutorial' || ...... [all the other entries that are to to route directly to] ... ) && me.isNew ) { $location.redirectTo('/tutorial') } - it would work but it messy, isn't really DRY and doesn't necessarily make it any easier to follow. but its a good steer, thanks.